# IEnumerable interface and Skip method in Mono

Tags: c#, mono, ienumerable, ilist

I'm looking for the [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) method of [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) interface.

[IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) public `IEnumerable` interface, so I thought I was able to access that method.

Anyway the following code fails to compile on Mono:

```
private static void SkipFirst(IList<float> list)
{
    IList<float> skippedFirst = list.Skip(1);
}
```

Here's the error:

> error CS1061: Type `System.Collections.Generic.IList<float>' does not
>   contain a definition for`Skip' and no extension method `Skip' of type`
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I doing wrong? How can I access that method from an `IList` interface?

Comment: try out adding reference to the `System.Core` package and `using System.Linq` in cs file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Skip` is an extension method, so it is not actually a method of any of the collection classes. Instead it is defined by Linq. You need to add a reference to Linq:
`using System.Linq;`

`list.Skip(1)` is just syntactical sugar, it is actually converted to `Enumerable.Skip(list, 1)`

Also, `Skip` returns `IEnumerable<T>` which means you need to use either

```
IList<float> skippedFirst = list.Skip(1).ToList();
```

or

```
IEnumerable<float> skippedFirst = list.Skip(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are forgetting `using System.Linq` in your usages.
2. Skip is LINQ method so you will need to convert to list after using skip with `ToList()` method.

The end result:

```
using System.Linq;

// some code

private static void SkipFirst(IList<float> list)
{
    IList<float> skippedFirst = list.Skip(1).ToList();
}
```

Comment: For completeness, it could well be that declaring `skippedFirst` as `IEnumerable<float>` is a better option than adding `.ToList()`; it depends on how `skippedFirst` will be used.